# How to calculate the start point and the end point of a circle based on points

Tags: math

I want bevel the sides of a rectangle in order to do so i want to draw a circle from the start point to the end point as shown in the image[image]

while drawing a complete circle this is how i do it

```
float angle = 2.0f * M_PI * i / iSegments;
// vertex data
float x, y, z ,tx,ty ,tz;
x = cos(angle)  * 50.0;
y = sin(angle)  * 50.0;
z = 0.0;
```

How do we calculate the vertices for the circle in the given case ?

Comment: When the center of the circle should be the rectangle center, then the circle would not align smoothly with the other edges. Are you sure you don't wan't an exact quarter of a circle?

Comment: @BDL The bevel would change according to the bevel size so the circle can be of any size.

Comment: So your image should probably look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4m3LE.png. Start and endpoint calculation are then more trivial because they are center + [0, radius] and center + [radius, 0].

Comment: @BDL The X and Y bevel distance will always remain same so it should be a Quarter of circle.

Comment: @BDL Currently i am using four triangles to form a rectangle and when applied bevel it would move the x , y positions of the triangle to create space for bevel

Comment: @shomit BDL picture shows you that circle center is at (70,70) and circle radius is (100-70=30). So quarter of the circle perfectly fits into square corner and conjugates smoothly. Points at the arc are  `cx+r*cos(angle), cy+r*sin(angle)` where cx,cy are center coordinates

Comment: @MBo Thank you i get it what BDL picture means working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The center of the circle is `radius` away from the corner point, both in x and in y directions. In your example the `radius` is 30. To draw an arc of 90° (π/2 radians), you can start with the first angle and divide π/2 into as many segments as you want. The first angle depends on the which corner of the rectangle is treated. In the example of the upper right corner, the starting angle would be 0°.

Here is some code to illustrate the concept:

```
// draw a circular bevel to a rectangle, given are
//   p_x, p_y: the coordinates of the corner, e.g. 50, 50
//   rad: the radius of the bevel, e.g. 30
//   dir_x: the direction to indicate whether the center of 
//     the circle lies lef (dir_y=-1) or right (dir_x=+1) of the corner
//   dir_y: the direction to indicate whether the center of 
//     the circle lies lower (dir_y=-1) or higher (dir_y=+1) than the corner

void draw_circular_bevel (float p_x, float p_y, float rad, int dir_x, int dir_y)
{
  float c_x, c_y;   // the center of the circle
  float start_angle; // the angle where to start the arc
  c_x = p_x + rad * dir_x;
  c_y = p_y + rad * dir_y;
  if (dir_x == 1 and dir_y == 1) 
    start_angle = 0.0;
  else if (dir_x == 1 and dir_y == -1) 
    start_angle = - M_PI * 0.5f;
  else if (dir_x == -1 and dir_y == 1) 
    start_angle = M_PI * 0.5f;
  else if (dir_x == -1 and dir_y == -1) 
    start_angle = - 2.0f * M_PI;
  for (int i=0; i <= iSegments; ++i) {
    float x, y;
    float angle = start_angle + 0.5f * M_PI * i / (float)iSegments;
    x = c_x + cos(angle) * rad;
    y = c_y + sin(angle) * rad;
    // here call code to draw a point or a segment at position x,y
  }
}
```